# Display Janrain/RPX popup only when needed

Tags: javascript, janrain

My webpage is accessible for users without sign in, but some action requires an authentication.

I would like to show the Janrain popup window only when the user clicked on the `Sign in` button. My webpages usually generated dynamically with Javascript.

As far as I know, the only way to show the popup is to include an `a` element to the page with `class="rpxnow"`, add the link to the `rpxnow.com/js/lib/rpx.js` script, and this script will add an `onclick` handler to my `a` element.

But I didn't have any `a` element when the page was loaded, and I don't like to waste the anonymous user's bandwidth with the unnecessary `<script>` tags on every page.

So my question is: how to attach the Janrain popup event trigger to a dynamically created HTML element?

Answer (score 2):

What's the language you are using? Just add the script tag when needed:

```
if ($require_authentication)
{
   echo "<script src='http://static.rpxnow.com/js/lib/rpx.js' ...";
}

if ($require_authentication)
{
   echo "<a class='rpxnow'>";
}
```

But you still need a  element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use Javascript, the page is a static html file.